# I have a problem with "MAKH", SQL constantly reports that the column is invalid

Tags: sql-server

My procedure does not work, it indicates that the `MAKH` column is invalid, I checked but could not find the cause

```
CREATE PROC SP8
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        MAVT, MAKH, SUM(SOLUONG) AS SLXUAT 
    INTO 
        #TPA
    FROM 
        CT70
    WHERE 
        NXT = 2
    GROUP BY 
        MAVT, MAKH


    SELECT MAVT 
    INTO #TEMP
    FROM CT70

    DECLARE @SQLSTR NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    SELECT @SQLSTR = @SQLSTR + 'ALTER TABLE #TEMP ADD ' + MAKH + ' 
                                NUMERIC(20,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;'
    FROM DMKH

    EXEC(@SQLSTR)

    DECLARE @SQLSTR1 NVARCHAR(MAX) ='';

    SELECT @SQLSTR1 = @SQLSTR1 + 'UPDATE #TEMP SET ' + (MAKH) + ' = SLXUAT 
    FROM #TPA 
    WHERE #TEMP.MAVT = #TPA.MAVT 
      AND #TEMP.MAKH = '+CHAR(39)+RTRIM(MAKH)+CHAR(39)+';' FROM CT70

    SELECT * FROM #TEMP

    EXEC(@SQLSTR1)
END
GO
```

How can I find the cause of this?

Comment: This statement is completely invalid: `SELECT @SQLSTR1 = @SQLSTR1 + 'UPDATE #TEMP SET '+(MAKH)+' = SLXUAT FROM #TPA WHERE #TEMP.MAVT = #TPA.MAVT AND #TEMP.MAKH = '+CHAR(39)+RTRIM(MAKH)+CHAR(39)+';' FROM CT70`. 1: the `FROM CT70` at the end indicates that this returns multiple rows, however the whole thing should build up one string assigned to a variable. 2: using `#TEMP` will generate an error because it is not after `FROM` as a source. You need to see what you want to do with these tables and build up the code according to that - maybe first with test tables without dynamic SQL.

Comment: Every component in my "procedure" works except it

Comment: Are you sure about `SELECT @SQLSTR = @SQLSTR + 'ALTER TABLE #TEMP ADD ' + MAKH + ' NUMERIC(20,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;' FROM DMKH`? Why not just `SELECT @SQLSTR = @SQLSTR + 'ALTER TABLE #TEMP ADD MAKH NUMERIC(20,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;'`? Why `FROM DMKH` necessary?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó this is a variable assignation trick to add several rows into a variable, it works but  it's not recommended though. And the dynamic SQL is to add a variable amount of columns to the temporary table. The columns names are stored in a table.

Comment: But if `MAKH` is not an actual column name but contains different column names, then `#TEMP.MAKH` is invalid - and only valid when `MAKH` is eventually `"MAKH"`. This means that EzLo's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your last dynamic query has a joining condition `AND #TEMP.MAKH`, and `#TEMP` doesn't have a column called `MAKH`.

What you are adding on the previous dynamic SQL are columns with *a column **reference** that's called* `MAKH`, but the actual column name is the content of the `MAKH` column from the `DMKH` table.

I can't give a solution since I don't know your intent and the data from the underlying table, unfortunately. Just make sure to `PRINT` the SQL before executing it, it will be pretty easy to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of
`AND #TEMP.MAKH = '+CHAR(39)+RTRIM(MAKH)+CHAR(39)+';' FROM CT70`
this:
`AND #TEMP.' + MAKH + ' = ' + CHAR(39)+RTRIM(MAKH)+CHAR(39)+';' FROM CT70`
to make `MAKH` a dynamic column of `#TEMP`.